# Get records from database ordered by year > month > day

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an `Item` model.

There are many records in the database with column `created_at` filled in.
I want to generate a view with such a hierarchy:

```
2014
  December
    31
      items here
    30
      items here
    29
      items here
    ...
  November
    31
    ...
  ...
2013
  ...
```

What's the most elegant way to do that?

**EDIT:** Thank you so much for queries. How do I get that worked in Ruby on Rails?

Comment: where would you like to see this? on the result pane of SSMS or somewhere else?

Comment: Well, I got uniq years from database:
`@years = Items.uniq.pluck("EXTRACT(YEAR FROM created_at)"`

I don't know, what's the next way is ċorrect for me

Comment: @Manish Dalal
I would like to get some array of nested arrays which I would use in my view file in nested loops. 
Like `items[:years][:months][:days]`

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, we will order the records by the parts of date. Sample query below

```
SELECT 
      ItemDescription,
      Year(DateField) AS Year,
      Datename(mm, DateField) AS Month,
      Day(DateField) AS Day
FROM tblName
ORDER BY
      Year(DateField) DESC,
      Month(DateField) DESC,
      Day(DateField) DESC
```

This will provide you the data in the order expected. Now you can either create a stored procedure to modify the output to the format you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT DATEPART(Year, PaymentDate) Year, DATEPART(Month, PaymentDate) Month,    DATEPART(day, PaymentDate) Day,item_name
    FROM Payments
    GROUP BY DATEPART(Year, PaymentDate), DATEPART(Month, PaymentDate),DATEPART(day, PaymentDate) desc
    ORDER BY Year, Month,day
```